# How to find the time complexity of a recursive function

Tags: time-complexity

```
Code(n){
if (n=0){
    print 1;
}else
    for (int i=1;i<2^n){
        Code(n-1)
    }
}
```

How can i write the time complexity in a recursive function?
The answer i came up with is T(n)=O(2^n)+T(n-1)*2^(n-1)+O(1)
since the for loop will run from 1 to 2^n hence the O(2^n) but i don't know how
to write the Code(n-1) part.

Answer (score -1):

The time complexity is O(2^(n*(n+1)/2)), which is O(2^(n^2)).

You see, this function's time complexity is like this:

`T(n) = 2^n * T(n-1)`

If you apply logarithm to this function, then you get:

`log2(T(n)) = n + log2(T(n-1))`

Now let log2(T(n)) be X(n), then you get:

`X(n) = n + X(n-1) = n + (n - 1) + X(n-2) = ... = n + (n-1) + ... + 1`

which is equals to `n*(n+1)/2`, so we get `T(n) = 2^(n*(n+1)/2)`, which is approximately equals to `2^(n^2)`.

By the way, I don't know how you came up with that recursive function.

Maybe you meant `for (int i=1;i<2^n) Code(i-1)`?

Comment: Thank you! Could you tell me how you reached that answer?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No, O(2^n) is absolutely not the same as O(2^(n*(n+1)/2)).

Comment: Yes, you're right. Edited.